# Access Object property with a dynamic property key

Tags: javascript

I need to access the "isTouched" property from a nested object. The challenge is that this property could either be shown like this:

```
form: { CHANGES: { isTouched: true/false } }
```

or

```
form: { 'formName': { isTouched: true/false } }
```

Accessing the first would straightforward with:

```
form.CHANGES.isTouched
```

however, I would like to have one method that can cater for both scenarios also considering that the form name will change based on whatever form is being used.

I thought about collecting all of the form names and loop through them but I think that would be not very effective.

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you mean. I think you want variable instead of hardcoded name. `form[variable_name].isTouched` can be used in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% I understand the question, but would something like this work for you?

```
k = Object.keys(form)[0]
form[k].isTouched
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) which will give you an array of object's own property names. Then you can simply access the first object name by using index:

```js
var form = { 'formName': { isTouched: true/false } }
var o = Object.keys(form)[0];
console.log(form[o].isTouched);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

```
/**
* Returns the value of the isTouched property from provided object.
* If formName specified, the value will be retrieved from the o[formName] sub object, otherwise from the default sub object accessed by key CHANGES
*/
function getIsTouched(o, formName){
    return o[formName] ? o[formName].isTouched : o.CHANGES.isTouched
}
```